# Android: Get GPS Location from Service in a Fixed Intervall

Tags: android, service, gps, alarmmanager, wakelock

I want to receive gps data like every 3 minutes from a service over a long time (3-4 hours).
It all works fine but I have some questions to which method is the best regarding battery lifetime.

1. Start the service, inside onCreate of the service create a partial wakelock, start a timer that is executed every 3 minutes. Get position data from inside the timer. When the service is stopped (after 3-4 hours) release the wake lock.
2. Use AlarmManager to start the service every 3 minutes. Inside the service create a partial wakelock, get the position data and then release the wake lock and stop the service.
3. Same as #1 but instead of a timer set the intervall through the requestLocationUpdates() method. (The reason why I don't like this method is that when I use a timer I can get like 5 positions (every 3 minutes) and pick the most accurate but when I set the intervall with requestLocationUpdates() I only get one position, which might be inaccurate, or am I wrong?)

I don't like the idea of leaving a partial wakelock for 3-4 hours thats why I think that #2 might be a better solution.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> // The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
> ```

```
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters
```

> ```
> // The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
> ```

```
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000; // 1 sec
```

> ```
> LocationManager locationManager; 
> locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
> locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
>                                          MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
>                                          MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
> ```

Comment: AFAIK min time between updates is only a hint which may or may not be implemented for a given device.